# Serve new subdomains dynamically

Tags: apache-2.4, web-server, virtualhost, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

I have a service `example.com` that needs to allow users to host a few files in their own subdomain `userpage-userabc.example.com`, similarly as does Github with `userabc.github.io`.

I currently use Apache, and each time I want to configure a new domain or subdomain, I have to create manually a new `<VirtualHost>`, restart the Apache server, etc.
This is not possible here.

Example: if a visitor creates a new account `userabc` (added in a database), how to make that the `userpage-userabc.example.com` subdomain is available, and automatically serving files from `/www/userabc/` or serving `http://userpage-userabc.example.com/` with `/www/main/index.php?user=userabc`?

Note: `*.example.com` already has a wildcard A DNS-record to redirect to my server

What's a simple lightweight tool to do this "dynamic subdomain creation"? (I currently use Apache, PHP, Python, but I can use other tools).

Or is it possible with a single `<VirtualHost>` that catches all sudomains `*.example.com` and a RewriteRule including the subdomain?

Comment: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=115522231#content/view/115522231

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/mass.html

Comment: Seems to be several ways to accomplish this. I don’t think you’ve put much research or thought in to this.

Comment: @Appleoddity Thanks for your comments. It's precisely because I have seen so many different methods and advice (such as "Use this plugin", "Move to nginx", "Use another server") that I miss the big picture of it, thus this question.

Comment: This is where you decide what works best for you and implement it. Nobody can make this decision for you. We just don’t know enough about your use case or your technical expertise. The good news is there’s lots of ways to do this.

Comment: @Appleoddity After further tests, I finally found what is probably the easiest solution with Apache + PHP and one single VirtualHost. Thanks for your help again!

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in a comment, here are references for Apache, there are multiple ways to do it: [Dynamically Configured Mass Virtual Hosting](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/mass.html), [Dynamic mass virtual hosts with mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/vhosts.html).

The simplest solution I have found after a few more tests is: one single `<VirtualHost>`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias *.example.com
  DocumentRoot /www/example
  <Directory />
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

with this wildcard `ServerAlias`.

With an `.htaccess` containing

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

we can then do all the routing for each user via PHP:

```
<?php
$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$sname = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
// parse the subdomain of $host or $sname and deliver 
// the content accordingly (using the database)
?>
```

Benefit: it also works if the final user is using *his own custom domain* with a CNAME DNS record. Example:

```
www.userabc.com CNAME userpage-userabc.example.com
```

Then in the PHP, `$host` will here show `www.userabc.com`. If this custom domain information is somewhere in the database, we can serve the content accordingly, even if the user is using a **custom domain**.

Note: in the case for which users use their custom domain with CNAME, this is useful to determine which is the default VirtualHost to use when a request comes with a host which is not listed in the `ServerName` directives:  [Apache default VirtualHost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427379/apache-default-virtualhost).

Comment: Just to add, you shouldn't add apex CNAME records like `userabc.com. CNAME userpage-userabc.example.com.`. DNS holds more than just `A/AAAA` and those will also be CNAME'd (see https://www.isc.org/blogs/cname-at-the-apex-of-a-zone/).

Comment: Thanks @Torin, correct, I modified to `www.userabc.com. CNAME ...`. Btw, how do people that use a custom domain with "Github Pages" or with a similar hosting service that works with custom domain do? The [GH Pages doc](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site/managing-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site) says we should  `www.johndoe.com.  CNAME  johndoe.github.io.`. But then how to do that `http://johndoe.com` serves the same content as `http://www.johndoe.com`? (if we cannot CNAME the `johndoe.com.`)

Comment: Some DNS software have a virtual `CNAME`-like record (sometimes called `ALIAS` or `ANAME`) which will return `A/AAAA` records of that other name. If your DNS software/provider allows you to use those types of records, they'd be fine, but otherwise you'd need to manually add the `A/AAAA` records and update them when they change. The [GitHub docs](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site/managing-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site#configuring-an-apex-domain) do mention about the IPv4/6 records you'd need to add.

Comment: Thanks @Torin! So in my example it should be `www.johndoe.com.  CNAME  johndoe.github.io.` and `johndoe.com.  ALIAS  johndoe.github.io.` or is the latter `johndoe.com.  ALIAS  www.johndoe.com.`?

Comment: Last thing @Torin: if ALIAS/ANAME are not available by DNS provider, can we use DNAME (which seems available)?

Comment: `DNAME` is like `CNAME` but for subnames, so it's also probably not what you want. If you're doing the GitHub pages, you'll probably want to add the four `A` records and the four `AAAA` records that are mentioned in the docs. It's a pain, but that's how it is :(